# Vue - how to validate data from Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I have a rather big form which I post to an API backend. The form has about 17-20 fields, depending on the status of a checkbox.

My plan is that after the user fills out the form I will validate it using Vuelidate and then display a summary of the data to give the user the possibility of reviewing their data. After the user reviews the data and considers that is correct, it posts the form to the backend API.

To do this, I plan on using Vuex to store the form object, and use the store to display the fields in the form and also on the summary page.

Is this a good approach, to store the form object in Vuex? If so, where I define the validation rules in store.js? 
Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really **need** Vuex for this. 
You can keep your form validation rules in your component itself. If you have something of a form builder or a different component that takes care of your form, you can keep your validation rules there or accept the entire form model through prop from the Component where you want to use the form.

Once the submission is done, you can pass the data to your Summary page via route itself. Check this out - https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Whenever you think about Vuex or any state management solution think about the lifecycle of that data. How long is it needed to persist. In most cases, you'll find that it belongs to one view or two.

Vuex is good for cases where you need a piece of data to persist for way longer, possibly entire duration of the app. Example - User Details, Theme Settings, Experience Configuration etc.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Now another issue, if I want to go back to review the form and maybe change something, how could I initialize the form on the first component. Now it comes out empty if I press back.

Comment: The same way your summary route accept props, you can also accept props in your first component and on create, you can check if that's available. If so, use the data to initialize your form fields

Comment: But if I press Back in the browser, I will not have any `props` to send, what would I do then?

Comment: I think you'll have because even if you press browser back button, its vue router which actually manages the route navigation. If you go back to a route using browser back button, it'll still trigger the lifecycle hooks.